# Djangorest framework. Required field only in viewset

Tags: django-rest-framework

Basically, required fields for viewset are based on `models.py` file. If I use `create` method and it is defined `blank=True` and `null=True` in `models.py` then this field is not required.

But how to define that this field is not required in `models.py` but required in `viewset.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it will be required by the serializer by setting this field's required to True.

If you don't want to explicitly define the field, you may take advantage of the [serializer's extra_kwags](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)